# Have the edit keyboard shortcut be equivalent to clicking on the edit link

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, keyboard-shortcuts

If there's a pending edit on a post, and I have editing privileges, clicking on the `edit(1)` link will open up the review panel. But pressing <kbd>e</kbd> will do nothing. It would be nice to have the review panel open up on pressing <kbd>e</kbd> in this case.

---

Even for people without edit privs, it'd be nice to see what edits are pending (so that if I had a different edit in mind, I could check back in later). That'd probably be a different feature request, though.